# What exactly does nfs4_disable_idmapping parameter do?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, nfs4

I've been experimenting with user/group ID mapping (translation) in NFSv4. What I want to achieve is name based ID translation, that is independent of the actual UID/GID on the server and clients.

Many guides and articles mention that to have ID mapping working you have to set `nfs4_disable_idmapping` parameter to `0` (aka N) in the `nfs` module on client, and `nfsd` module on the server. However, I didn't find any information or documentation about what exactly this parameter does.

As an experiment, I configured NFSv4 server and client (with `sec=krb5`) and I deliberately left these parameters at their default value (mapping disabled).
I can verify that the mapping is disabled on server:

```
$ cat /sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping 
Y
```

and on the client:

```
$ cat /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping 
Y
```

I created users `bob(uid=1002)` and `sam(uid=1001)` on the server, and users `bob(uid=1003)` and `sam(uid=1004)` on the client. As you can see, the UIDs do not match, however, the users are still mapped correctly. File created by the `bob` user on the is seen as owned by `bob` on the server, and vice versa.

Moreover, if I look at the logs on the client:

```
nfsidmap[1874]: key: 0x322c739a type: uid value: bob@home.lan timeout 600                                            
nfsidmap[1874]: nfs4_name_to_uid: calling nsswitch->name_to_uid                                                      
nfsidmap[1874]: nss_getpwnam: name 'bob@home.lan' domain 'home.lan': resulting localname 'bob'                       
nfsidmap[1874]: nfs4_name_to_uid: nsswitch->name_to_uid returned 0                                                   
nfsidmap[1874]: nfs4_name_to_uid: final return value is 0
```

and on the server:

```
rpc.idmapd[1717]: nfsdcb: authbuf=gss/krb5p authtype=user                                                                                                                   
rpc.idmapd[1717]: nfs4_uid_to_name: calling nsswitch->uid_to_name                                                                                                           
rpc.idmapd[1717]: nfs4_uid_to_name: nsswitch->uid_to_name returned 0                                                                                                        
rpc.idmapd[1717]: nfs4_uid_to_name: final return value is 0                                                                                                                 
rpc.idmapd[1717]: Server : (user) id "1002" -> name "bob@home.lan"
```

they both suggest that ID mapping is indeed working *"by name"* rather then *"by id"*.

So my question is: what is `nfs4_disable_idmapping` parameter for then, if it seems not to have any observable effect on the ID mapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You hit a bad test case. According to kernel [documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#n2708) `nfs4_disable_idmapping` option makes sense only when `sec=sys` is used.