# issue with playbook script

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, ansible-playbook

How can I write a playbook to

1. Make sure both NFS server and client  listen to same domain in `/etc/idmapd.conf` and confirmed with `nfsidmap -d`

```
[General]

Verbosity = 0
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
# set your own domain here, if it differs from FQDN minus hostname
Domain = localdomain

[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup
```

2. Also Enable the id mapping in `/sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping`

It is currently Y and I need it to be N. I tried running the playbook below but I get an error:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Run command to enable id mapping
      become: true
      lineinfile:
        path: /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping
        regexp: 'Y'
        line: 'N'
        state: present
```

3. Finally Run the command `nfsidmap -c`

Comment: "i tried runnign the playbook below but i get error" Well, what does that error say?

Answer (score 0):

For the CLI commands you can use [`shell` – Execute shell commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html).

```yaml
- name: Display the system's effective NFSv4 domain name on 'stdout'
  shell:
    cmd: nfsidmap -d
  register: result
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: false
  failed_when: result.rc != 0

- name: Show result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

You may compare it then with [Ansible Facts - `ansible_domain`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) and if gathered.

For your configuration file you could use a [`template` – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) `idmapd.conf.j2`.

```
[General]

Verbosity = 0
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
# set your own domain here, if it differs from FQDN minus hostname
Domain = {{ ansible_domain }}

[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup
```

Looking into [what exactly does `nfs4_disable_idmapping` parameter do](https://serverfault.com/questions/949642/) there seems to be no need for your complex approach. Just make sure there is a file which contains `N` would be enough.

```yaml
- name: Make sure ID mapping is enabled
  copy:
    content: 'N'
    dest: /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping
```